# How does a question become unclosed?

Tags: support, closing-questions

My original question was closed due to 'possible duplicate'. This was by accident because the question I meant to ask was not the question that I asked.

So, I edited my question by wording it better. As far as I know, and I've searched, there are no duplicates. Can/Does my edited question become "unclosed"? If so, when?

Here's the link to my question:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24163/prove-one-standard-deviation-lies-on-inflection-points

Answer (score 6):

Much of the information relevant to this question can be gained by reading about the [SE privilege to cast close & reopen votes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) after gaining 3k reputation.

For what it's worth, I have now cast a reopen vote for your edited question. It still requires 4 more reopen votes from >3k rep users, or a vote from a moderator.

Comment: I will follow the link to your question and cast my first vote to reopen. +1 Well done gung.

Comment: It looks like the linked question is not closed.  If it was at CV it has been migrated to Mathematics is open there and is getting answers and comments.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, it was closed. It was reopened / migrated to math shortly after my reopen vote (like 15 minutes later).